# How to sort tableview cell by distance which calculate after the data loaded in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

After I success grab all data from firebase, I have calculate the distance between user and post and display on tableview by using latitude and longitude grab from firebase. I trying to use the distance I have calculate to sort the tableview cell but no idea how to. I m new and I really need some advise, thanks in advance.

Comment: show us anything, do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

When you design your UIViewController, having a UITableView, you should start from having view models, to be able to build tableView cells. So having an array of viewModels, on which depends the tableView, you just sort the array by your required criteria and trigger `tableView.reloadData()`.